# Jenkins run batch command only at periodically build and not at polling build

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I have a problem with Jenkins. I have a Jenkins Job and in there i run multiple batch commands. I have a Build periodically which build the job at midnight. And I have a Poll SCM, which builds the project when there is a change. I create a CodeCoverage Report in an Batch file. This batch file runs at the Build periodically and the Poll SCM build (Polling build). But I only want to create the CodeCoverage Report at the periodically build. Has someone an idea how to realize this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two sets of actions to do, then you might really want two different jobs.

This is in fact how most of the projects I have setup run.  There are both periodic (daily) and polled scm (commit) jobs.  The heavy lifting (clean build, code analysis, extensive testing, scm metric gathering) is only done for the daily builds.  The commit builds are kept light weight (incremental build, smoke tests).